# How to disable a link if the link is not from the previous link

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

How to disable a link if the link is not from the previous link

Like : https://example.com/ReffLink/ThisLink

People Must From previous Link First Then The Link page go

But People Dont Just Search https://example.com/ReffLink(Without click See This Link)/ThisLink(Locked)

Comment: You could use the HTTP-Referer? It's possible to get around it with a MITM software like Burp, but it's nontrivial and easier to just click one link first.

Answer (score 0):

This should be done server-side.  Otherwise, it's trivial for people to override the check on the first link.

You will need to set a cookie when the first page is loaded.  Then on the second page, check for the existence of that cookie before allowing the second page to load.  Otherwise, redirect to the first page.

You didn't mention which server-side tech you're using if any, so I can't provide you a more specific answer than that.  But, that's the general idea.  Most any server-side framework allows you set cookies/session data.